# NLTK tokenize but don't split named entities

Tags: nltk, tokenize, named-entity-recognition

I am working on a simple grammar based parser. For this I need to first tokenize the input. In my texts lots of cities appear (e.g., New York, San Francisco, etc.). When I just use the standard nltk word_tokenizer, all these cities are split.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
word_tokenize('What are we going to do in San Francisco?')
```

Current output:

```
['What', 'are', 'we', 'going', 'to', 'do', 'in', 'San', 'Francisco', '?']
```

Desired output:

```
['What', 'are', 'we', 'going', 'to', 'do', 'in', 'San Francisco', '?']
```

How can I tokenize such sentences without splitting named entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identify the named entities, then walk the result and join the chunked tokens together:

```
>>> from nltk import ne_chunk, pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> toks = word_tokenize('What are we going to do in San Francisco?')
>>> chunks = ne_chunk(pos_tag(toks))
>>> [ w[0] if isinstance(w, tuple) else " ".join(t[0] for t in w) for w in chunks ]
['What', 'are', 'we', 'going', 'to', 'do', 'in', 'San Francisco', '?']
```

Each element of `chunks` is either a `(word, pos)` tuple or a `Tree()` containing the parts of the chunk.